# How to get channel ID through bot - Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to get the channel ID of where the command was sent so that I can use that ID to delete the channel. I've been looking in the Discord.js doc's but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: <TextChannel>.id

Comment: [TextChannel.id](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=id) [TextChannel.delete()](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=delete) [Message.channel](https://discord.js.org/?source=post_page#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=channel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simply

```js
message.channel.id
```

`message.channel` is your current text channel and `id` is the ID of it.

Comment: When I use that, I get the error message that `message.channel.id is not a function`. I'm using the `message.channel.id` like this: `const channelId = message.channel.id();` and then use it later on as `channelId.delete();`.

Comment: Yes just remove the`()` at id, because `id` is not a function ^^ I don't know why you did `id()` as is is not displayed in my example. @Arcitezz

Comment: @Arcitezz and to delete that channel, you have to make: `message.guild.channels.cache.get(channelId).delete()`

Comment: @Arcitezz I just explained it in a comment ^^

Comment: Sure, no problem